# Ubuntu on Hyper-V vs Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I currently run Lubuntu inside Virtualbox on top of OSX (an iMac).  For my purposes (Linux software development), this works fine.

Recently, I have been considering getting a Win8 Pro box.

**If I want to set up the same Linux development environment, should I be using Hyper-V instead?**

I have been reading some old posts that I/O performance is much better under Hyper-V (compared to VBox), but I don't know if this is still true - compiling code is basically CPU and I/O bound.  I probably will have to end up trying both Hyper-V and VBox, but if anyone has any recent experience here, please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use the machine in a headless server-only capacity - then hyper-v may have better IO performance.

However, if you intend to use any desktop aspects at all, Hyper-V offers extremely poor Linux integration compared with Virtual Box.